# Why is js not updating my data in HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a quiz game but my HTML page is not being updated by JavaScript.
I also think that json is not loading.

[In this image,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wxe4.png) in place of dummy questions and answers are expected but they are not being loaded in main page.
I think innerHTML is not loading my data on main HTML page.

```js
var quizData = [
    {
        question: "Who discovered charge as positive and negative?",
        a: "Benjamin Franklin",
        b: "Narendra Modi",
        c: "Abdul Kalam",
        d: "Lalu Yadav",
        correct: "a",
    },
    {
        question: "Which charge is free to move?",
        a: "negative",
        b: "postive",
        c: "both a and b",
        d: "none of the above",
        correct: "a",
    },
];

var quiz=document.getElementById("quiz");
var answerEls=document.querySelectorAll(".answer");
var questionEl=document.getElementById("question");
var a_text=document.getElementById("a_text");
var b_text=document.getElementById("b_text");
var c_text=document.getElementById("c_text");
var d_text=document.getElementById("d_text");
var submitBtn=document.getElementById("submit");

let currentQuiz = 0;
let score = 0;

loadQuiz();

function loadQuiz(){
    deselectAnswers();

    var currentQuizData = quizData[currentQuiz];

    questionEl.innerText = currentQuizData.question;
    a_text.innerText = currentQuizData.a;
    b_text.innerText = currentQuizData.b;
    c_text.innerText = currentQuizData.c;
    d_text.innerText = currentQuizData.d;
}

function getSelected() {
    let answer = undefined;
    answerEls.forEach((answerEl) => {
        if (answerEl.checked) {
            answer = answerEl.id;
        }
    });

    return answer;
}

function deselectAnswers(){
    answerEls.forEach((answerEl) => {
        answerEl.checked = false;
    });
}

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    var answer = getSelected();

    if(answer){
        if(answer === quizData[currentQuiz].correct) {
            score++;
        }
        currentQuiz++;
        if(currentQuiz < quizData.length) {
            loadQuiz();
        } else { 
        quiz.innerHTML = `
        <h2> You answered correctly at $(score)/${quizData.length} questions.</h2>
        <button onclick="location.reload()">Reload</button> 
        `;
        }
       }
});
```

```css
import url("https://font-googleapis.com/css2?family-Poppins:wght@200;600&display=swap");
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    background-color: #b8c6db;
    background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #b8c6db 0%, #f5f7fa 100%);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.quiz-container{
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(100 , 100, 100, .1);
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 600px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.quiz-header{
    padding: 4rem;
}
h2{
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0%;
}
ul li{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    margin: 1rem 0;
}
button{
    background-color: #8e44ad;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1.3rem;
}
button:hover{
    background-color: #5e3370;
}
button:focus{
    background-color: #5e3370;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Quiz App</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="quiz-container" id="quiz">
        <div class="quiz-header">
            <h2 id="question">Question Text</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="a" name="answer" class="answer">
                    <label for="a" id="a_text">Question</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="b" name="answer" class="answer">
                    <label for="b" id="b_text">Question</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="c" name="answer" class="answer">
                    <label for="c" id="c_text">Question</label>
                </li>
                <li>    
                    <input type="radio" id="d" name="answer" class="answer">
                    <label for="d" id="d_text">Question</label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <button id="submit">Sumbit</button>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code example has syntax errors. May you please fix them first?

Comment: Actually, I am not able to solve it

Comment: How come you are not able to?

Comment: `quiz.innerHTML = '\
        <h2> You answered correctly at $(score)/${quizData.length} questions.</h2>\
        <button onclick="location.reload()">Reload</button>\
        ';` and `var submitBtn=document.getElementById("submit");` at least get you a working example.

Comment: Or you can use a template literal (which you probably meant to use since you have `${}` inside the string) `quiz.innerHTML = \` ... \`;`

Comment: Also `getElementById` not `getElementsById`.

Comment: As @evolutionxbox points out, the easiest way to use newlines in a string is to make it a template literal--change the quotes (') to backticks(`).

Comment: Sorry for the churn folks. I clicked the Tidy button in the snippet and it went nuts :).

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the dev console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in js file

```js
quiz.innerHTML = `
        <h2> You answered correctly at ${score}/${quizData.length} questions.</h2>
        <button onclick="location.reload()">Reload</button> 
        `;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You should move `script` after the body, if script is loaded before page, it can't access DOM elements.
And `script.js` has some syntax errors

at line 27 in `script.js`,
It should be `getElementById`

```
var submitBtn=document.getElementById("submit");
```

at line 74, enclose the string in backticks (`) to use template literals

```
quiz.innerHTML = `
    <h2> You answered correctly at ${score}/${quizData.length} questions.</h2>
    <button onclick="location.reload()">Reload</button> 
    `;
```

[corrected source code here](https://replit.com/@priyansh32/JubilantAjarExam)

Comment: There is another syntax error I missed. It should be `${score}` not `$(score)` at line 74

Answer (score 0):

You should move `<script src="script.js"></script>` to the bottom of the body tag after the elements have been initialised.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Quiz App</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="quiz-container" id="quiz">
        <div class="quiz-header">
            <h2 id="question">Question Text</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="a" name="answer" class="answer">
                    <label for="a" id="a_text">Question</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="b" name="answer" class="answer">
                    <label for="b" id="b_text">Question</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="c" name="answer" class="answer">
                    <label for="c" id="c_text">Question</label>
                </li>
                <li>    
                    <input type="radio" id="d" name="answer" class="answer">
                    <label for="d" id="d_text">Question</label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <button id="submit">Sumbit</button>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```